# Intermittent CLI API 500 when Downloading File

Tags: jenkins, google-drive-api

I'm using a `gdrive` CLI command on a Jenkins web node to automatically download a file from Google Drive during a build process.

This use to work, however, recently (As of a week or two ago) the command to download the file intermittently started producing 500 errors with no message.

The command that's being run is: `gdrive download query "name = '16.7.3.zip'"`.

Sometimes the above command downloads the file, but, sometimes it doesn't. Here's an example of the error output:

[image: Google Drive Download Query Error]

Is anyone able to give advice on where to start with this issue, is it something on Google's side?

I've read a few articles explaining that this *might* be throttling from the API, however, I'd have expected a different error code, i.e. 403 with the error *"The download quota for this file has been exceeded."*.

I have the following specs installed:

- gdrive: 2.1.0
- Golang: go1.6
- OS/Arch: linux/amd64

Comment: Please post your code we cant debug what we cant see.  ideally supply a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @DaImTo - The error is being produced in using _only_ the CLI command, of which i've posted above, along with the responses i'm getting. There are no more pieces to this puzzle than those.

Comment: For reference, i've opened a issue on the GitHub package account; https://github.com/prasmussen/gdrive/issues/300.

Comment: That's probably the best place for this I dont think anyone here will be able to help without seeing the code which is causing the error.

Answer (score 0):

Intermittent 500 errors are allowed for in the Google Drive API. You simply need to do an exponential backoff and retry. Generally they are caused by internal timeouts within the Drive infrastructure. Sometimes these are related to service problems, other times they can be caused by a request that causes a large amount of work.